# Spring @Transactional method doesn't rollback

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, testing

I've got a question to Spring, hibernate and testng.

I am developing an app and try to write a transactional unit test. The question is how could I rollback my database operation when my buissnes method is marked as "transactional"?

The code:

```
@Test
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:applicationContext.xml" })
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = true)
public class SampleTest extends
AbstractTransactionalTestNGSpringContextTests {


@Autowired
private AuthorDao authorDao; 

@BeforeTest
void createAppCtx() {
    ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            "/applicationContext.xml");

}


@Test
void testStg() {

    Person person = new Author();
    person.setFirstName("Edward");
    person.setLastName("Kowalski");
    authorDao.createAuthor(person);
}
```

In my authorDao I've following method:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class AuthorDao {

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;


public AuthorDao() {

}

public AuthorDao(EntityManager entityManager) {
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
}

public Author createAuthor(Person author) {
    entityManager.persist(author);
    return (Author) author;
}
```

}

If the application context is needed, I can also attach it. 
So as you can see the buisness method is transactional so there is a commit after calling. So point is how to avoid commit in the test class?
Is it possible?

Many thanks for help.

EDIT:
applicationContext:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">


<context:component-scan base-package="pl.hs" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="myTxManager" /> 


<beans>


    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="jdbcPropertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        p:location="classpath:project.properties" />

    <bean id="myDataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
        p:driverClassName="${hibernate.connection.driver_class}" 
        p:url="${hibernate.connection.url}"
        p:username="${hibernate.connection.username}" 
        p:password="${hibernate.connection.password}" />


    <bean id="persistenceUnitManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager">
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="defaultDataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="myEmf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="pl.hs" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="myTxManager" name="myTxManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="myEmf" />
        <!-- <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" /> -->
    </bean>

</beans>
</beans>
```

Persistnce.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
                            http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">

<persistence-unit name="pl.hs"
    transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

    <class> myJavaClasses </class>




    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>

        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />



        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"></property>
    </properties>


</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: Why are you loading the context yourself? Springs test framework already does that for you and, as currently setup, will rollback your transaction.

Comment: Ok, I removed the method createAppCtx(), but it still does not rollback the transaction

Comment: If you are using MySQL make sure you are using transactional tables (InnoDB type).

Comment: I am using oracle 11g if that helps

Comment: Have you setup transactions correctly? Can you add your `applicationContext.xml` and, if you have, your `persistence.xml`.

Comment: With what you posted here a transaction should be started for your test and rolled back. There must be something you have left out that is in your actual code that isn't here. I also doubt that that is the `applicationContext.xml` as loaded by the test case, the `<mvc:annotation-driven />` would fail because it needs a web application context instead of a regular context, looking at how it is posted it looks like a copy/paste from multiple files (the mvc stuff is above the beans tag...).

Comment: Actually this will be a web application. The only thing left out is: "@repository on authorDao class" and 'viewResolver' for future webapplication

Comment: There must be something else because, as stated, what you posted here wouldn't even work as it would crash your testcase. At least if `mvc:annotation-driven />` is part of your `applicationContext.xml`.

Comment: Now - see yestarday evening updates. There is nothing more. I just changed  slightly bean `myEmf`. After TestStg record appears in the DB. And as stated - this will be an webapp, so that's way I have `<mcv:annotation driven>/`

Comment: For starters try removing the nested `<beans />` tags as that doesn't add anything but complexity here. When using the `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` you can ditch the `persistenceUnitManager` also if this is really it you really have something strange as what you want is the default for Spring transactional tests (and judging from what you posted you are extending `AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests`. One other thing you might want to try is remove the `@Test` from the class and only leave it on the method.

Answer (score 0):

Add @Transactional to the test method too so that the TransactionConfiguration applies.

Comment: The `AbstractTransactionalTestNGSpringContextTests` has `@Transactional` defined on the class, so no need to add it to the method again.

Comment: What is your database? do you have AUTOCOMMIT = ON ?

Comment: I am using Oracle 11g and have autocommit: off

Answer (score 0):

The [TransactionConfiguration](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/transaction/TransactionConfiguration.html#defaultRollback--) starts a new transaction when the test starts and it rolls it back at the end of the test.

So you don't have to do anything special to roll the current transaction.

If you wanted to add another logic unit after:

```
authorDao.createAuthor(person);
```

then you'd better write another test method.

Each test should verify one and only one behavioural unit. If you have several responsibilities tested in a single test method, then you should break those into several tests.

Comment: Yes, I know. But I have a 'count in the next test and the result is affected because of the 'createAuthor' and new row in the db

Comment: @RunWith is used for jUnit testing, I am using testNg. Is there a annotation for testng?

Comment: I guess it's only AbstractTransactionalTestNGSpringContextTests. Somehow the transaction is not properly taken into consideration.